# How to execute AT commands on rooted Xperia P

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, sony-xperia

How can I execute AT commands in a rooted Sony Xperia P? I did a lot of on-line search but couldn't find anything useful! Please refer to below command output:

```
root@android:/ # getprop | grep -i ril                                         
[gsm.version.ril-impl]: [ST-Ericsson u300-ril R2B]
[init.svc.ril-daemon]: [running]
[ril.cat.first.start]: [false]
[ril.ecclist]: [112,911,]
[ril.icctype]: [1]
[rild.libargs]: [-c UNIX -n 2 -p /dev/socket/at_core -s /dev/socket/at_core -i rmnet]
[rild.libpath]: [/system/lib/libu300-ril.so]
root@android:/ #
```

The path obtained for `rild.libargs` is: `/dev/socket/at_core`

Here is the directory listing of `/dev/socket`:

```
root@android:/ # cd /dev/socket/                                               
root@android:/dev/socket # ls -l
srw-rw---- root     radio             2014-07-03 10:05 at_core
srw-rw---- bluetooth bluetooth          2014-07-03 10:05 bluetooth
srw-rw---- root     radio             2014-07-03 10:05 catd_a
srw-rw---- root     radio             2014-07-03 10:05 cn_event
srw-rw---- root     radio             2014-07-03 10:05 cn_request
srwxrwxrwx nobody   nobody            2014-07-03 10:05 cops.socket
srw-rw---- bluetooth bluetooth          2014-07-03 10:05 dbus
```

I'm really not sure how to execute simple AT commands via this interface. Any idea please? Your help will be highly appreciated!